What is the difference between an administrator account and a device owner account
I installed Windows 10 on SSD and went to account settings and saw something I do not understand. I am wondering if there is a difference between Device Owner and Administrator accounts.
Does the Owner account have system-level rights that are similar to Administrator? Or what is the difference?

PS. I used search but did not find an answer. Thank you for your help in advance.


This question should include more details and clarify the problem. I suspect "Device Owner" is just a local Administrator account

Thanks! That is, the rights and capabilities are the same as those of the administrator, right? (I'm using standard Windows 10 22H2 x64, and this program too standard).

@Artern - It's your system.  You need to tell us if my analysis of the user group is indeed correct.

Based on this article, you better use Administrators group.
https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-security_groups.html
"This group is not currently used in Windows.
Default User Rights:
Allow log on locally: SeInteractiveLogonRight
Access this computer from the network: SeNetworkLogonRight
Bypass traverse checking: SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
Change the time zone: SeTimeZonePrivilege"
